# If consciousness is an emergent property of brain state, does this mean that we can only truly exist for 1 Planck unit of time?

Tags: philosophy-of-mind, consciousness, time, mind-body, neurophilosophy

Suppose my self-awareness, consciousness, point of view (POV) or [**qualia**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Qualia) is not a "thing in itself" but rather an intrinsic emergent property of my brain's current brain state.

Then, as my brain state constantly changes every nanosecond (or rather [**Planck unit of time**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planck_time) to be precise), does that mean that my POV can only exist for 1 Planck unit, only to be replaced by a new POV the next Planck unit, which in turn is also replaced by a new POV the next Planck unit, and so on and so forth?

Suppose the answer is YES. In that case, let’s say that during my lifetime 1 trillion POVs were aware of my brain/body (assuming a countable, discrete time series). Now, let’s say my “self-awareness”, that is the “awareness that I exist in this universe” or “Cogito ergo sum” or “POV” or "qualia" was one of those 1 trillion POVs that occurred during the lifetime of this body/brain.

This would mean that *if* I was aware of my existence, I could *only* have been aware of it for 1 Planck unit, after which *I should have stopped existing*. 
Then, *how* do you explain the fact that I’m constantly experiencing the illusion of being aware of my existence? Shouldn’t I have stopped existing by now?

Shouldn’t I be experiencing complete blankness, or more accurately, shouldn’t I be in a eternal state of non-existence, since my 1 Planck unit chance of being aware of my existence is already gone? So why am I in this constant illusion of being aware of my existence?

Isn't this a contradiction?

**UPDATE**:
Another way to put it: *If* consciousness (or POV) is a complex property calculated as a function of brain state, then arguably each brain state maps to a unique POV. This is because the probability of a brain having exactly the same brain states in 2 different instants is practically zero, and their corresponding emergent POVs are consequently very likely different as well. In other words, POV<sub>1</sub> which is aware of experience at instant *t<sub>1</sub>* is totally different from POV<sub>2</sub> which is aware of experience at instant *t<sub>2</sub>, t<sub>2</sub>* > *t<sub>1</sub>*. So, *if* I identify myself as any POV at any given instant *t,* then by the moment the next instant arrives, "my" POV (the one that allowed me to be aware of my existence at instant *t*) is destroyed and a new POV arises which has nothing to do with "my" POV (already dead by now). So according to this line of reasoning, any consciousness/qualia can only be aware of its corresponding brain/body for 1 Planck unit before it vanishes into nothingness.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/75991/discussion-on-question-by-xwb-if-consciousness-is-an-emergent-property-of-brain).

Answer (score 1):

## The Ruler Of The Universe already asked the question

[Douglas Adams](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Douglas_Adams) hit upon this dilemma in [*The Hitchhiker's Guide To The Galaxy, Fit the Twelfth*](https://youtu.be/3YToxpyH-fw?t=19m15s) (shift-click to listen), later written in [*The Restaurant At The End Of The Universe*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Restaurant_at_the_End_of_the_Universe), and even goes a bit further.

SPOILER ALERT: The "[Ruler Of The Universe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_minor_The_Hitchhiker%27s_Guide_to_the_Galaxy_characters#The_Ruler_of_the_Universe)" turns out to be an old man living in a shack with a cat, and he is a perfect [solipsist](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solipsism).

> **Ruler Of The Universe**: Ah, this is a question about the past, is it?
>
> **Zarniwoop**: Yes
>
> **Ruler Of The Universe**: How can I tell that the past isn’t a fiction designed to account for the discrepancy between my immediate physical sensations and my state of mind?

So the Ruler Of The Universe takes your question even further and asks: How can we be sure that there even **is** a passage of time? Maybe the past is just an illusion? How can we know that it is not?

The answer is: **we cannot know this**. There is no way to escape the possibility that Hard Solipsism presents, namely that everything we feel and remember — including the passage of time — could be nothing but a huge illusion.

If we relax the solipsism a bit and assume that 1) the physical world is real and 2) the passage of time is real, then the answer becomes: **the persistence of the material world**.

The fact that matter and energy can exist without spontaneously poofing out into nothingness — instead they are persistent and does not change form spontaneously — is what enables it. If you are material, and your brain-state emerges from some of that material, then the persistence of the material world means that your consciousness will also persist.

Comment: Ok, but even if the past is an illusion and the universe was just created 1 nanosecond ago and all our memories were hardcoded to make us believe that we've been around for a while ... my question would still hold for that moment onwards, because from that moment onwards you would still face a constant flow of brain states, with their corresponding POVs. Right?

Comment: How can you know? How can you be **sure** that the memories you have of having had previous brain-states is **not** an illusion?

Comment: If you ask me about certainty, in that case we cannot be sure about anything. How can you know if the feeling of having a sound, logic reasoning is not a mere illusion being imposed on your mind by an evil genius? How can you trust your thoughts? How can you trust your inner dialogue or your natural language? You cannot rely on logic or anything because, who knows, maybe someone is making you have the feeling of trust on those things when maybe you shouldn't. But back to the question, the question is based on suppositions: IF this and this THEN why? I'm not asserting that the IFs are true.

Comment: Well, the simple answer to that is: **the persistence of the material world**. The fact matter and energy can exist without spontaneously poofing out into nothingness — instead they are **peristent** and does not change form spontaneously — is what enables it. If you are material, and your brainstate depends on the material, then the persistence of the material world enables your consciousness to be temporally contiguous.

Comment: Persistent for how long? What is the threshold that determines that there is too much of a brain state change for your POV to still exist before it gets replaced by a new one?

Comment: @xwb That was not the question. You asked about your **experience**. Your **experience** depends on how fast your material brain take in, process and store information. And that is a **slow** process. If things happen too fast, you are not even experiencing it... it just flits past you so fast that your mind can only process the wake it leave behind. And conversely, if things happen **too slow**, then you are also not aware of them happening.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/75823/discussion-between-michaelk-and-xwb).

Comment: But how do you define the border between the reality and illusions if everything is an illusion?

Comment: @rus9384 Use the chat please, link 2 comments up.

Comment: Why does invoking solipsism help here? I don't think this makes anything clear at all.

Comment: @Discretelizard It helps in that it forces us to make assumptions if we want to answer the question. We have to make the assumption that the physical world is real and that the passage of time is real. With that we can conclude that they physical world is **persistent** throughout the passage of time. This persistence helps us answer the question: because we are physical, and therefore persistent, our consciousness is persistent instead of just blinking out.

Comment: @MichaelK, so are you saying that after death our consciousness remains, since the the physical body still remains?

Comment: @xwb Since all the (until then) ongoing physical/physiological processes that make up the consciousness have **ceased** (that is how we define death), no. Also: use the [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/75823/discussion-between-michaelk-and-xwb).

Answer (score 1):

The brain creates the content of consciousness, not the the consciousness itself, which happens to exist as a semi-permanent point of view within the brain.  So while the ephemeral flood of electromagnetic activity in the brain is transient the self that observes its content is stable and solid.

Yes..it is interactive dualism.  I wrote about it here:
https://philpapers.org/rec/SLETLO-2

Answer (score 0):

Existence is a metaphysical thing therefore it cannot only be limited to our consciousness nor our brain.

Let's do the following thought experiment: A machine that makes perfect copies of people is invented. You enter the machine and at the exit there is yourself and 5 copies of yourself. ¿Which one would be you? They all have the same memories, personality, tastes and physical appearance but you can only move one of those bodies and think in one of those brains, in fact you couldn’t tell if you are a copy or the original one. If those 6 six copies of you left the machine they all would start having their own agenda and change their personality and physical appearance in time. In fact your body renews at its atoms and cells in time so you are not yourself but the illusion of yourself.

What is existence? I take the Buddhist/Vedanta approach as plausible. It's just one conciseness in different copies or avatars in time and space playing with itself. If so there is not past nor future. There is no birth nor death and everything happens here and now.

Comment: If it's only one consciousness, then how do you explain that I am not aware of your brain/body now?

Comment: That's a different question. Consciousness and time and space don't go hand in hand. You sleep 8hours a day. Does that mean that you stop existing?

Comment: I don't know. It depends on what you mean by "you". If you mean the physical body, in that case it doesn't stop existing. If you mean consciousness .. well, it depends on what consciousness really is. For example, if consciousness is an emergent property of brain state, then you have the question I'm already asking here.

Comment: Can you quote the part of my last comment that made you think "everything that is not conscious doesn't exist"?

Comment: The existence of the conscious and the existence of the unconscious are not mutually exclusive necessarily. I don't remember ever saying that. In my question I'm basically asking whether our conscious part, our self-awareness (which basically allows us to know that we exist, otherwise we would just be philosophical zombies) has any significant duration whatsoever IF the assumption that it's an emergent property of brain states happens to be TRUE (hypothetically).

Comment: So you are saying that you only exist when you question about your existence? You think questioning your existence is too different from watching a football game for instance? Do you question your existence 24x7 otherwise you would cease to exist? Perhaps your question should be oriented to neuroscience.

Comment: Or psychology...?

Answer (score 0):

If each frame of consciousness has the prior frame for reference - which is reasonable - then I would posit that it behaves in a similar manner to a movie reel. Each frame is independent, but together they form a sum greater than their parts - a seemingly flowing product of independent states.

Answer (score 0):

> Suppose my self-awareness, consciousness or point of view (POV) is not a "thing in itself" but rather an intrinsic emergent property of my brain's current brain state.

*If* I have to agree to that supposition, and these implied conditions:

1. That "brain state" must be taken to mean the state of one's brain at an arbitrarily small level of description--so, the exact state of every subatomic particle in every cell and bit of fluid within the brain counts.
2. That's one's point of view or consciousness is *a thing* that has *only* a precise 1-to-1 mapping to any given brain state at any arbitrarily small slice of time (rather than a *process*, a series of steps that require significantly more time to carry out) and which has perfectly sharp boundaries for what is and isn't your consciousness.
3. That it is sensible to speak in terms of consciousness--or, for that matter, functional brain circuitry activity changes--in any way occurring over an interval of time of 0.00000000000000000000000000000000000000000001 second (the Planck time).
4. That's one point of view or consciousness is perfectly equivalent to "yourself".

**Then, yes,** admitting that a brain like any physical object above absolute zero Kelvin (or, more likely, all objects always) is in constant physical change at *some* level, **under this supposition, with these defined conditions**, a new "you" winks into--and out of--existence every Planck period.

Let's stay with this model for a bit. You then ask:

> Shouldn’t I be experiencing complete blankness, or more accurately shouldn’t I be in a eternal state of non-existence, since my 1 Planck's period chance of being aware of my existence is already gone?

If by "I" you mean any "I" at any *previous* Planck periods, then yes: all of those "former yous" *are* in "an eternal state of non-existence". (But you are right to correct yourself, since non-existent "yous" can't experience complete blankness--because they can't experience anything.) Under this model, the "you" of December 4th, 2017 at 2:03:02.00000000000000000200000000000070000000000001 is indeed gone, maybe forever (he could return in the rather unlikely event of your brain finding itself in the same state...you [never know](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eternal_return).)

> So why am I in this constant illusion of being aware of my existence? Isn't this a contradiction?

No, because at any given time, according to this model, there is a "current you" that *is* conscious. That you may only last one Planck time, but he is replaced immediately in the next Planck time with a new officeholder. During waking life, there is a never a point in which there is "nobody home".

Comment: Although it is true that there would always be "somebody home", a contradiction still holds in the fact that it would not be possible for a SINGLE awareness/POV to remain at home for many Planck periods in a row (or, to be more precise, it's infinitesimally unlikely), and YET that's what we normally experience. There is not much available space in the comments, so let me refer you to this [link](https://www.quora.com/Why-wasnt-my-consciousness-generated-by-another-brain-Why-am-I-linked-with-this-brain/answer/Robert-Walker-Smith-1/comment/59078958#), it explains this idea much more clearly

Comment: I wouldn't call it a *contradiction* as much as just all your "POVs" simply being incorrect. All this reminds me of much of the story of Clive Wearing. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clive_Wearing . Read the first paragraph, then read starting from "In a diary".

Comment: And btw, I hope it is clear from how I wrote my comment that your model is wrong/unrealistic/absurd (sorry) in many ways, so although it is intellectually interesting to pursue its implications, it doesn't correspond well to reality. I say that in part because I've noticed people out there on the internet who actually get emotionally disturbed by these thoughts.

Comment: Don't restraint yourself out of fear of hurting my feelings. You didn't. Anyways. The Clive Wearing analogy is not totally accurate, because in that case the guy's brain is in fact forgetting the past, whereas in my thought experiment your brain is normal and healthy with full access to past memories, it's just that the POVs being aware of them are being replaced constantly. And the contradiction comes from the fact that you realize your current POV is the real one, because Cogito ergo sum, and you should expect to disappear the next moment, which never happens.

Comment: Additionally, can you elaborate more on why this model is absurd? Are you saying the emergence model is wrong? Are you a dualist? Do you believe that awareness/consciousness/POV is a "thing in itself"?

Comment: @xwb Yes, Clive is almost the "photonegative" of your model, in that he stays conscious but thinks he doesn't; in your model, we don't stay conscious, but think we do. I didn't say Clive was an exemplar of your model, merely that it reminded me of him. Re: your 2nd point: But in your model, You1 DOES disappear in the next moment...replaced by someone, You2, *who (mistakenly) thinks he is You1*.

Comment: @xwb Re: why your model is wrong, we would need to take this to chat to work out why (particularly since that doesn't answer your original question). If you start a chatroom and alert me, I'll join and try to explain.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/75949/discussion-between-xwb-and-chelonian).